# How to replace oid with string in net-snmp agent perl

Tags: perl, net-snmp, mib, oid

I am struggling with the problem of building a snmp agent to receive a snmpwalk  like this:

> NET-SNMP-TMC-MIB::nsTMCState."tmcd" = INTEGER: 3 
>   NET-SNMP-TMC-MIB::nsTMCState."drecd" = INTEGER: 3 
>   NET-SNMP-TMC-MIB::nsTMCInfo."tmcd" = "" 
>   NET-SNMP-TMC-MIB::nsTMCInfo."drecd" = STRING: "Apps: FDPser[1]" 
>   NET-SNMP-TMC-MIB::nsTMCErrors."tmcd" = ""
>   NET-SNMP-TMC-MIB::nsTMCErrors."drecd" = ""

For now, I am able to get response:

> NET-SNMP-TMC-MIB::nsTMCState.1 = INTEGER: 3
>   NET-SNMP-TMC-MIB::nsTMCState.2 = INTEGER: 3
>   NET-SNMP-TMC-MIB::nsTMCInfo.1 = ""
>  NET-SNMP-TMC-MIB::nsTMCInfo.2 =
>   STRING: "Apps: FDPser[1]"
>  NET-SNMP-TMC-MIB::nsTMCErrors.1 = ""
>   NET-SNMP-TMC-MIB::nsTMCErrors.2 = ""

It is there a way to do this with perl ?
All responses are appreciated

Comment: How are you doing this? Please [edit] your question and include your code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to add entries to a table with OCTET STRING
index. You can google for how those are indexed, and the MIB will likely
say that they are variable-sized, so your index will be of the form:

n.subid1.subid2....subidn

where n is the length of the OCTET STRING, and subidj is the ASCII value
of the j-th character in the OCTET STRING.